# How to remove script tag depending on the reactjs router?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've integrated a third-party chatbot with the help of script tag in the public/index.html.
But on some urls I don't want to show the chatbot at all.

How can I remove the script tag depending on the url before/after it loads.

*public/index.html:*

```
     <body>
      <div id="root"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
        (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/<TOKEN_ID>/default';
        s1.charset='UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
        })();
      </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Are you using with react??

Comment: You can hide the bot element on location change in vanilla

Comment: which router are you using? Rather than removing it, I would only add it on the routes that need it. That's much easier.

Comment: @PratapSharma yes using react 16.12.0

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Once this script runs it includes the chatbot script and since react router routes change without page reloads the script will be loaded in memory and even if you remove the tag the chatbot will still be functioning. You should instead check the specific chatbot documentation on instructions on how to destroy it when you don't need it

Comment: @ChristianFritz  How can we do that with react-router 5 or 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
const script = document.getElementById("script_id");

if (script) {
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) to dynamically inject scripts into the Html
document and to use useEffect to cleanup the injected scripts,like this

```js
const component = () => {

useEffect (() => {

return () => {

document.getElementById("id_1").remove();
}
},[])

return(
<>
<Helmet>
<script src="..." id="id_1" />
</Helment>
   <div>
     hello world
   </div>
</>
)

}
```

this way the script is loaded only for the specific pages and not accessible for other pages.cheers!